# How can I run Test::Perl::Critic in parallel?

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, testing, perl-critic

I've written a simple test case based on [Test::Perl::Critic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Test::Perl::Critic) which runs `critic` on every single source file in the repository (`all_critic_ok`). However, this test takes a long time, especially since I also use a [Perl::Tidy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Perl::Tidy) policy.

Normally, criticizing different files is not dependent on other critics, so I thought I could parallelize those tests. As it turns out, [TAP::Harness](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/TAP::Harness) can indeed parallelize tests, but only file-wise, not test-wise.

How would you parallelize those tests? Any workaround will do.

Answer (score 3):

[Hack #68](http://books.google.com/books?id=p0HXkstjihAC&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=run+test+suites+persistently&source=bl&ots=Uz3ifsFBPP&sig=BT7HYcguJl0Y35KRxCKEeg_fGaQ&hl=en&ei=6dfoSv9_hpKUB-mZ7JkN&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CA0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=run%20test%20suites%20persistently&f=false) in [Perl Hacks](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596526740) has a recipe for running tests persistently using [PersistentPerl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/PersistentPerl). You might be able to adapt it for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large number of files, then creating multiple Test::Perl::Critic test scripts might not be such a bad idea.  For example, Perl-Critic itself has three Test::Perl::Critic scripts: one for checking application code, one for test code, and another for the *.run files.  And each of these uses a slightly different set of rules.

So if you can divide your code into at least two logical groups and create separate Test::Perl::Critic scripts for them, then you can get at least 2x performance improvement by running them in parallel with Tap::Harness.

Additionally, you can activate the PPI cache (see the Test::Perl::Critic documentation for directions).  But that will only make a modest performance improvement.

If you're really interested in making Test::Perl::Critic truly run in parallel, then you're very welcome to contribute code.  You can register for a commit bit at http://perlcritic.tigris.org.